# Values not passed to dynamic query in sql server

Tags: sql, debugging, dynamic

Is it possible to print the Dynamic select statement after passing the parameters values.When i print the SELECT @SQL.It is giving only select statement without parameter values.In my below procedure the dynamic select statement not giving correct output after passing the parameters.But when i directly passing the the parameter values into the select statement it is giving correct output.In my below procedure splitting function is working fine.Else part in 
if statement is not working properly.

```
CREATE TYPE TableVariable AS TABLE
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    field_ids        INT,
    value    VARCHAR(MAX)
)


Alter PROCEDURE Testing
(
    @TableVar TableVariable READONLY,
    @Catalog_id INT


)
AS
Declare @maxPK INT
Declare @pk INT 
Declare @fid INT
Declare @is_List SMALLINT
Declare @val VARCHAR(MAX)
Declare @field_Type VARCHAR(50)
Declare @Where VARCHAR(MAX)
Declare @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
Set @pk = 1
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
     Select @maxPK = count(*) From @TableVar 
     SELECT @Catalog_id
     Set @SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT v1.entity_id from values v1 inner join listings l ON v1.entity_id = l.entity_id WHERE l.c_id=@Catalog_id'

While @pk <= @maxPK
BEGIN


     SELECT @fid= field_ids FROM @TableVar where id=@pk;
     SELECT @val= value     FROM @TableVar where id=@pk;
     SELECT @field_Type=type,@is_List=is_list FROM FIELD WHERE ID=@fid
     IF (@is_List = 0) 
        BEGIN
     SET @SQL += ' and exists (select 1 from values v'+convert(varchar(15),@pk+1)+' where v1.entity_id = v'+convert(varchar(15),@pk+1)+'.entity_id and v'+convert(varchar(15),@pk+1)+'.field_id=@fid and(value IN(SELECT val FROM spliting(@val,'',''))))' 
     SELECT @fid
        END
     else IF (@is_List = 1 OR @field_Type = 'xy')
        BEGIN
        SET @SQL += ' and exists (select 1 from values v'+convert(varchar(15),@pk+1)+' where v1.entity_id = v'+convert(varchar(15),@pk+1)+'.entity_id and v'+convert(varchar(15),@pk+1)+'.field_id=@fid and(value in(@val)))' 
        SELECT @fid
        END
     Select @pk = @pk + 1

END
EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@Catalog_id int,@fid int,@val varchar(max)',@Catalog_id=@Catalog_id,@fid=@fid,@val=@val  
SELECT @SQL
END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

    END CATCH

END
DECLARE @DepartmentTVP AS TableVariable;
insert into @DepartmentTVP values(1780,'Smooth As Silk Deep Moisture Shampoo,Smooth As Silk Deeper Moisture Conditioner')
--insert into @DepartmentTVP values(1780,'Smooth As Silk Deeper Moisture Conditioner')
insert into @DepartmentTVP values(1782,'037-05-1129')
insert into @DepartmentTVP values(2320,'["fairtrade","usda_organic","non_gmo_verified"]')
SELECT * FROM @DepartmentTVP
EXEC Testing @DepartmentTVP,583
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes right before the statment:

```
EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@Catalog_id int,@fid int,@val varchar(max)',@Catalog_id=@Catalog_id,@fid=@fid,@val=@val
```

type:

```
print @SQL
```

Comment: This is my original query.Values are passed directly in the query.It is returning values.But in procedure it is not.
SELECT DISTINCT v1.entity_id from values v1 inner join listings l ON v1.entity_id = l.entity_id WHERE l.c_id=583 and exists (select 1 from values v2 where v1.entity_id = v2.entity_id and v2.field_id=1780 and(value IN('Smooth As Silk Deep Moisture Shampoo','Smooth As Silk Deeper Moisture Conditioner'))) and exists (select 1 from values v3 where v1.entity_id = v3.entity_id and v3.field_id=2320 and(value in('["fairtrade","usda_organic","non_gmo_verified"]')))

Comment: Print @sql is not working.It is not giving select statement with parameter values.